# How to include spaces (and other non-identifier characters) in MATLAB application name?

Tags: matlab, matlab-deployment, mcc

When we choose Name for our application we can't use space or other some characters for it. We need something like underline to separate words ! How can I get rid of this? It hasn't a good appearance for a compiled app that has a shortcut on desktop with underline between words for the name because the application name must be a valid C identifier in `MATLAB`.

Thanks.

Comment: Don't ask "why" something is, just ask "how" to do the task (it gets a better response on SO). And, for another question .. ask another question (in a different post).

Comment: Having space in file name is a terrible idea. I am sure there are  ways to configure the installer to make the name on the desktop be something not related to the file name? I have many icons on my desktop, and the name next to these icons has nothing to do with the actual application (.exe) name itself on the desk. It is just a label. You should be able to configure it this way also.

Comment: @Nasser. Thank you for your comment. How can i change name of shortcut automatically when application is installing?

Comment: This has nothing to do with Matlab. When I did an installer for a Matlab app, I used a free installer for windows. Try inno for example. In the configuration section for Inno, you set the label for the icon. See http://www.jrsoftware.org/ishelp/topic_taskssection.htm  again, this is a configuration issue with the installer you use for your application. There are other free installers and also commercial installers. But the concept is the same. It is a label for the desktop icon, which can be anything and has nothing to do with the actual file name itself.

Comment: @Nasser. Thank you. Can you describe more in answer mode?. What files we must insert to that program? Compiled installer of our app or raw files or compiled app?

Comment: Last time I build an installer for windows for a matlab .exe was few years ago. But all these questions you are asking, as described in details in the manual of any installer you decide to use to package your application in. It is standard windows installation process. Once you decide on which installer software to use to package your app in, then you read the instructions for that specific installer, and it will tell you everything you need to know. Try Inno, it is free and easy to learn. In one day you can figure it out.

Comment: @Nasser. But I need to install MCR besides my app like MATLAB installer. How can I do that?

Comment: You put all the needed files, libraries in your installation tree. If you have never done an installer before, may be you can download Inno and practice. You have to make an installation tree from your source tree first, copy there all the needed files required at run time (icon, dll's, fig files, your matlab .exe, etc...) (this is done by writing a script, which the installer will run). The installation script is based on this tree layout. inno (or whatever installer you are using) will generate a windows installer. Test it on your pc few times to make sure it works. Read the tutorials.